# PHP - Remove duplicates from foreach

Tags: php, foreach, duplicates

In Magento i have an Array with products and from those products i want to have the categories where they are in. That's what i have, but I'm using a foreach to get through the products, so there are duplicates that need to be removed.

I have the category names already with the foreach, but there are some duplicates now that need to be removed.

```
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <div class="bk-all-products">
        <?php
            $bk_product_id = $_product->getCategoryIds(); 
            $bk_category_id = $bk_product_id[1];

            $categoryId = $bk_category_id;
            $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $category = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')
            ->load($categoryId);
            $bk_category_id_name = $category->getName();

            echo $bk_category_id_name;

            echo "<br><br>";
        ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Additional information**

This is what is returns when I also print the Array in the foreach:

Array ( [0] => 354 [1] => 362 [2] => 360 [3] => 414 ) Cafeïnevrije koffie

Array ( [0] => 354 [1] => 362 [2] => 364 [3] => 414 ) Cafeïnevrije koffie

Array ( [0] => 354 [1] => 367 ) Koffiepakketten

Array ( [0] => 354 [1] => 364 ) Filterkoffie

Array ( [0] => 354 [1] => 360 ) Espressokoffie

Array ( [0] => 354 [1] => 360 [2] => 414 ) Espressokoffie

Array ( [0] => 354 [1] => 364 [2] => 414 ) Filterkoffie

Array ( [0] => 354 [1] => 360 [2] => 414 ) Espressokoffie

Array ( [0] => 354 [1] => 367 ) Koffiepakketten

Array ( [0] => 354 [1] => 367 ) Koffiepakketten

Array ( [0] => 367 [1] => 354 ) Koffiebonen

Array ( [0] => 367 [1] => 354 ) Koffiebonen

Comment: Use an array to store the outputted ones in, befoure outputting one, test if it's in the array

Comment: Duplicate products or duplicate categories across products in the collection?

Comment: Do it in the sql query maybe it's better by grouping similar products or categories

Comment: Why not select `DISTINCT` in the SQL query? Otherwise, if you don't have control over that, you can use `array_unique()` which can also be extended to have another argument indicating the sorting behavior of the resulting array.

Comment: @DarkBee How can I store the output from the $bk_product_id[1]; in an Array and loop through them to remove the duplicates?

Comment: @Mido Yes, but this Array is only per product to show the categories where the product is in. This is not an Array with the categories that I need from the products already, I think I need to make a new array from $bk_product_id[1]; but I have no idea how...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way would be to store the already displayed categories in an `Array` and check if the one you want to display is not already in it using [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

**EDIT:** probably better to store the id than the name, as you can avoid getting the name if already fetched:

```
<?php
$diplayed_categories = []; //initializing array
foreach ($_productCollection as $_product):
?>
    <div class="bk-all-products">
        <?php
            $bk_product_id = $_product->getCategoryIds(); 
            $bk_category_id = $bk_product_id[1];

            if(!in_array($bk_category_id, $diplayed_categories)){ //testing if not in array
                $diplayed_categories[] = $bk_category_id; //filling the array

                //moved inside the if, no need to fetch it again if it exists
                //$categoryId = $bk_category_id; //useless var
                $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $category = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')
                  ->load($bk_category_id); //replaced by $bk_category_id
                $bk_category_id_name = $category->getName();

                echo $bk_category_id_name;

                echo "<br><br>";
            }
        ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```